# Tablefunc in Redshift to pivot table not supported?

Tags: pivot, amazon-redshift, crosstab

I am trying to pivot a table in Redshift. This answer is instructive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/3063339
However, when I run the

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

command I get the error:

```
syntax error at or near "EXTENSION"
```

Does redShift not support the syntax above, or `tablefunc`, or neither? If so, are there any RedShift functions that could act as a workaround? I am aware a table can be pivoted with basic postgresql commands `SUM(CASE ...)` etc. These do not scale well for large tables though. Many thanks.

Comment: From what I read [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=126369) thare is no dedicated pivoting function in RedShift altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createextension.html) was introduced with Postgres 9.1.
[Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html) Only selected features from later versions were implemented.

I does not seem like Redshift supports the extension [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) *at all*. You'll have to use `CASE` statements to emulate the functionality. Here is a [related post on the AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=126369) (that you already found in your comment).

Comment: Exactly the link I provided in my comment above :-) Bad news for redshift users though. Thanks.

Comment: @Audrey: Yup, Redshift isn't Postgres, by a long shot. Sorry I didn't give credit, missed the link.